# Spring Security CAS: show client error on login.jsp

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-security, cas, spring-security-cas

I'm using `Spring Security` with `CAS` and have the following issue. When the authentication error is thrown from `CAS Server` (e.g. invalid username/password) it is shown well in form and is displayed correctly using tag:

```
<form:errors path="*" id="msg" cssClass="alert alert-danger" element="div"/>
```

But in cases when `CAS Server` returns success and the `AuthenticationException` is thrown on `CAS Client` none of the errors are displayed as basically `CAS Client` redirects back to `http://localhost:8080/cas/login?service=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fj_spring_cas_security_check`

So I can't really display what went wrong on the client side. Is it somehow possible to display an error from client on the same `JSP` in case it throws `AuthenticationException`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if that's the super clean and right way to do it, but the way I've managed to do that is using cookies.

All I had to do is to extend `SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler`, get there last authentication exception using `request.getSession().getAttribute(WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION)`
 and write my custom error code cookie. The code is in `Scala`, but is pretty straightforward:

```
class CookieAuthenticationFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler{

  val clientErrorCookie = "clientError"

  override def onAuthenticationFailure(request: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse, exception: AuthenticationException): Unit = {
    val authenticationException = SecurityUtility.getSessionAuthException(request).getOrElse(exception)

    ClientErrors.values
      .filter(clientError => clientError.exceptionClass.equals(authenticationException.getClass))
      .foreach(clientError => response.addCookie(new Cookie(clientErrorCookie, clientError.errorCode)))

    super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, authenticationException)
  }
}
```

Then, on the `CAS server` side I've displayed error on `JSP` in the following way:

```
<c:set var="clientErrorCookie" value="clientError"/>
<c:if test="${cookie.containsKey(clientErrorCookie)}">
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <spring:message code="error.client.authentication.${cookie.get(clientErrorCookie).value}"
                                        text="Client authentication error"/>
                    </div>
                </c:if>
```

And after the page is loaded and error is shown, I've just removed that cookie in `JS`:

```
function deleteCookie(name) {
            document.cookie = name + '=; Path=/; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
        }

$(document).ready(function(){
          deleteCookie('${clientErrorCookie}');
        }
```